# Get entities for TypeORM via getMetadataArgsStorage()

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have a nestjs program that uses typeorm. I've been using it for quite some time now and everything was fine until recently. I have a my connection config like so:

```
config = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    database: 'xxxx',
    entities: getMetadataArgsStorage().tables.map(tbl => tbl.target),
    synchronize: true,
};
```

All my old tables were created automatically, but I added a new entity with the annotation `@Entity` and it's not showing in the `getMetadataArgsStorage().tables` and therefore not created. Is there a way to update the value of `getMetadataArgsStorage().tables`?

My new entity look like this:

```
import { Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Entity } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class NewEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;
    @Column('text')
    text: string;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't specify entities like this: `entities: [`${__dirname}/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}`]`?

Comment: It works for creating the tables but when I try to make a query I always get this kind of error: 

RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "User" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?